# tftpd_hpa on ubuntu 14.04 not working

Tags: tftp

I have an english installation of Ubuntu 14.04 desktop with a french keyboard.
I have tried several time to install tftpd-hpa and nothing works.
here is the log for the install

```
elyham@elyham-Vostro-1720:~$ sudo apt-get install tftp-hpa 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tftp-hpa
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/17,7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 77,8 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package tftp-hpa.
(Reading database ... 200602 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tftp-hpa_5.2-7ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tftp-hpa (5.2-7ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up tftp-hpa (5.2-7ubuntu3) ...
elyham@elyham-Vostro-1720:~$
```

Then I try to rrestart the sercice and I got this

```
elyham@elyham-Vostro-1720:~$ 
elyham@elyham-Vostro-1720:~$ sudo service tftpd-hpa restart
tftpd-hpa: unrecognized service
elyham@elyham-Vostro-1720:~$
```

I don't understand what happened
Need some help!!

Comment: I've made a mistake. I was installing the client thinking it was the server. that's why it fails. The correct command is : 'sudo apt-get install tftpd-hpa' instead of 'sudo apt-get install tftp-hpa' the 'd' is missing

Answer (score 0):

I've made a mistake. I was installing the client thinking it was the server. That's why it fails.

The correct command is:

```
sudo apt-get install tftpd-hpa
```

instead of

```
sudo apt-get install tftp-hpa
```

The "d" was missing; that's the solution.